# Can't seem to get variables set in controllers

Tags: plugin-development, templating, variable

I think I might be confused by https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions

I have a controller that I want to return a model when validation fails:

```
$post = craft()->request->getPost();
$requestModel = Micros_AuthModel::populateModel($post);

if ( ! $requestModel->validate())
{
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'requestModel' => $requestModel
    ));

    $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
}
```

I assumed I would have access to requestModel in the template that posted:

```
{% if requestModel is defined %}
    {{ inspect(requestModel) }}
{% endif %}
```

But I that inspect() call never fires.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close!  You want to redirect on success and let the request continue as normal on validation failure.

```
public function actionMyPluginAction
{
    $post = craft()->request->getPost();
    $requestModel = Micros_AuthModel::populateModel($post);

    if ($requestModel->validate())
    {
        // Yay! What I did works!

        $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
    }

    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'requestModel' => $requestModel
    ));
}
```

Comment: OK, so when I redirectToPostedUrl() how can I get the data that was posted originally (to repopulate the form) and display the errors in the model?

Comment: Ah got it: craft.request.getPost().